# Gaussian surface without any charge inside it

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Suppose a Gaussian surface has no net charge inside it. Does it mean that the electric field $E$ is necessarily zero at all points on the surface? And is the converse also true? Can this be shown mathematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not necessarily 0.
You can think about Gauss Law this way: It relates the total flux of the eletrical field to the net charge inside the surface, it is a direct relation between eletrical flux and charge inside. The flux is necessary 0, not the eletric field.
Picture a point charge and a gaussian surface beside it ( but not with it inside ), the field is clearly not 0 at all points of the surface but the flux is.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Consider the field around a point charge
$$
\mathbf{E} = \frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}\;.
$$
This is not zero anywhere (except at infinity). Now consider any closed surface which does not enclose the charge. The total charge enclosed is therefore 0 but at no point on the surface is the field 0. However the net flux entering and leaving the surface is 0.

Comment: Why is it not zero?

Comment: We have an explicit formula for the field at every point in space, and it is never 0.

Comment: I mean why is the field intensity not zero at this Gaussian surface which is not enclosing any charge?

Comment: Because the field intensity is not zero anywhere... Gaussian surface included

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't --- it means that there's an equal flux of electric fields leaving the surface and entering the surface. For an example, try constructing some Gaussian surfaces around an electric dipole.

Comment: How will I prove this mathematically?

Comment: And it seems that you did not get my question.I want to know whether I can prove mathematically that the electric field intensity is not necessarily 0 on the Gaussian surface even if there is no charge enclosed by the surface.

Comment: Look at any diagram of the electric field around a dipole. Draw a Gaussian surface someplace where the field isn't zero. Compute the flux integral --- you get zero if the surface encloses both charges and nonzero if you only enclose one charge.

Comment: I am not trying to bring "electric dipole " into consideration.

Comment: And in your case charge(s) is enclosed......but in my question I said that the Gaussian surface should not enclose any charge .

Comment: Your question (v1) says "no net charge." I was suggesting taking equal-but-opposite charges and separating them by some nonzero distance, but I used a distracting technical name.  But if you're integrating around a dipole field, you'll also get zero net flux if your Gaussian surface encloses neither charge.

Comment: Quite true....my mistake.....yes we can consider an electric dipole

Comment: And one more thing ...what about the electric field on the Gaussian surface as specified in the question.